# Determine monotone intervals of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$ f(x) = \int_1^{x^2} (x^2 - t) e^{-t^2}dt. $$ We need to determine monotone intervals of $f(x)$. I tried to differentiate $f(x)$ as follows.
$$ f'(x) = \left(x^2 \int_1^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt \right)' - \left(\int_1^{x^2} te^{-t^2}dt\right)' \\
= 2x \int_1^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt  + 2x^3e^{-x^4} - 2x^3e^{-x^4} \\
= 2x \int_1^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt. $$
But it seems that we are not able to compute $\int_1^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt$ explicitly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is that actually necesary? You know that for every |x|>1 the integral is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral $\displaystyle\int_1^{x^2} e^{-t^2}\,dt$ is positive when $x^2>1$ and negative when $0\le x^2<1$.  That means it is positive when $x>1$ or $x<-1$, and negative when $-1<x<1$.  You're multiplying it by $2x$ which is positive when $x>0$ and negative when $x<0$.

So the derivative is negative when $x<-1$, positive when $-1<x<0$, negative when $0<x<1$, and positive when $x>1$.

Answer (score 2):

You needn't compute it explicitly, but only determine the sign.

$f'(x)=0$ for $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$. Just check it.

Now notice that
$$\int_1^{x^2}e^{-t^2}dt$$
is positive for $|x|>1$ and negative for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f'(x)=0 \iff x \in \{ -1, 0, 1\} $. It suffices to show that $ \displaystyle\int_{1}^{x^2} e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t $ is positive for $|x|>1$ and negative for $|x|<1$. Do you see why this is?